# How to create synthetic mortality data set?

Tags: dataset, synthetic-data

Mortality data for certain countries is available for at the Human Mortality Database (www.mortality.org). However, I would like to develop a multipopulation model that first estimates a mortality model for the reference population (e.g. a whole country) and subsequently incorporate features of this model in the mortality model for a subpopulation  (e.g. a region that has a significant higher mortality experience), which is too small to directly model the longterm trend and cohort effects. Thus, I rather model the difference of the subpopulation from the reference population.

As no data is available for the subpopulation, I would like to generate a synthetic dataset to exemplary show how the model would work. My ideas so far have been to

- Merge data from two countries and model it as the reference population and treat the data from the smaller country as the subpopulation. Problem: the populations are not really related and strongly regional-dependent factors such as the cohort effect are totally different for the subpopulation.
- A naive approach: Generate a new dataset by assuming a certain size of the population and use the same mortality intensity less x per cent.
- Modify the above approach by sampling the percentage drawback e.g. from a uniform distribution in a certain interval.

Answer (score 1):

Adrian Raftery's ICM webinar from a couple of weeks ago on Bayesian population projections may provide some guidance to addressing your question...

http://www.methods-colloquium.com/#!Adrian-Raftery-Bayesian-Population-Projections/clv6/56180f810cf2c3576e55c39e

As he notes, mortality and population tables are among the most stable of structural factors in national statistics due to the long range "march" of generations or cohorts. This makes their projection much easier, more robust and accurate.

One approach worth considering would be an agent-based simulation of the difficult-to-identify subpopulations based on mortality data as well as the many other developing country population demographic metrics (e.g., TFR) available from, e.g., the UN, the WHO, etc. ABMs are widely used in simulating complex systems. Here are some papers on ABMs:

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=agent+based+models